# Exporting data file in For loop

Tags: export

I prepared a code in which some numerical data can be produced.
I want to export the data in terms of counter of loop but I don't know how I can do it. It my please if someone who knows, helps me.
Here is my code.

```
 Clear["Global`*"]

 m0 = 1; 
 ω = 1;
 m = 1;

 For[γ = 0.1, γ <=  1, γ = γ + 0.1, 

 ψ[x_] =  Sqrt[m0/(1 + γ x^2)^2] E^((-ω m0 )/(2 γ) ArcTan[x Sqrt[γ]]^2) HermiteH[m, Sqrt[(ω m0)/γ] ArcTan[x Sqrt[γ]]]; 

 A = NIntegrate[ψ[x]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}];

 n = 1/Sqrt[A];

 Ψ[x_] = n ψ[x];

 Subscript[S, x] =  NIntegrate[Ψ[x]^2 Log[Ψ[x]^2], {x, -∞, ∞}];

 Print[γ, "    ", Subscript[S, x]]]


0.1    -1.43033

0.2    -1.49253 

0.3    -1.53077

0.4    -1.54978

0.5    -1.55519

0.6    -1.55161

0.7    -1.54224

0.8    -1.52921

0.9    -1.51391

1.    -1.49725
```

Answer (score 2):

My thoughts:

1. Don't use `For`. Either act with functions on lists using `Map` or `Apply` etc., use `Table`, or if you *must* loop, use `Do`.
2. It's rare to see  the syntax `f[x_] = ...` used with great success, because this syntax evaluates the RHS immediately. Probably you mean to define a function that computes the RHS for every input `x`. The syntax for this is `f[x_] := ...`
3. Don't redefine functions inside loops if you can avoid it. In the loop only `γ` changes, so make `ψ` an *expression* in `x`, depending on `γ`, instead.
4. Avoid `Subscript` for anything except pretty-printing in plot labels etc. They often don't behave the way we naively think.

With all this in mind, here is the rewritten code:

```
 m0 = 1; 
 ω = 1;
 m = 1;

 ψ[γ_] :=  Sqrt[m0/(1 + γ x^2)^2] E^((-ω m0 )/(2 γ) ArcTan[x Sqrt[γ]]^2) HermiteH[m, Sqrt[(ω m0)/γ] ArcTan[x Sqrt[γ]]];

 sx[γ_] :=  Module[{a, n, normpsi},
   a = NIntegrate[ψ[γ]^2, {x, -∞, ∞}];
   n = 1/Sqrt[a];
   normpsi = n Ψ[γ];
   NIntegrate[normpsi^2 Log[normpsi^2], {x, -∞, ∞}]
 ]
```

If you want one result per value of `γ` you can for instance do

```
Do[sx[g] >> ToString[g]<>".txt", {g, 0.1, 1, 0.1}]
```

The part `ToString[g]<>".txt"` generates a .txt file with a name depending on the value of `g`, which I guess is the main thing OP is asking for. One can also use `Export` in this way.

**UPDATE**

To export all the values in the format specified in the OP, one way is

```
Do[ToString[γ] <> "    " <> ToString[sx[γ]] >>> "data.txt", {γ, 0.1, 1, 0.1} ]
```

Here we use `>>>`, AKA `PutAppend`, to add new lines to the file for each value of `γ`.

Comment: + , but note the non-delayed set is fine in cases where nothing on the r.h.s (excepting the function arguments) is going to change (which seems to be the case here).  I'd argue delayed set `:=` is somewhat over used.

Comment: @george2079, the classical counterexample goes like `x = 3; f[x_] = 2 x + 1; f[18]`. However, I can agree that `:=` is sometimes overused, and especially if the RHS needs subcalculations that can be done symbolically, I would sometimes prefer *expressions*, and then injecting values using `With` or `Replace(All)` :)

Comment: Many thank for your kind points. But the mail problem and actually my goal in this code is production a data file which includes data as it was shown at the end of code.

Comment: Aha. See my updated answer.